# How do I run a Python program in Windows?

Tags: python

I have downloaded the Python package from the website. It is in my C drive, in a directory named `Python27`. In the command prompt, I type the following:

```
cd C:\Python27
python
```

Then I get Python 2.7.4. and the opening message. My Python file, called first.py, is in the desktop, and I don't know how to access it. I've tried the following..

```
python first.py
python first.py
python cd Desktop\first.py
python cd Desktop\"first.py"
```

What is the correct command?

Comment: Are you trying to change directory to the folder holding the file?  (Also, if you could put the output when you attempted those commands, it would help.)

Comment: The Desktop directory on Windows is `C:\Users\<USERNAME_HERE>\Desktop`, I believe.

Comment: Did you try `C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\username\desktop\first.py` ? (assuming no space in the username and no c:\python in the path).

Comment: Alternatively, right click on the python file on the desktop and select [always] open with this program. Then select the python binary.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [add python to your path](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=960000&fromSeriesID=96), then you can open a command line in the directory of your file and type:

```
python first.py
```

Comment: i have already added python to my path, i think

Comment: Then open up a command line, `cd` to your file's directory, and type the command I wrote above.

Comment: Note that you need to type this BEFORE opening python

Answer (score 0):

If your program does not need the console (e.g. automation scripts or GUI programs), then double click on the script file to execute it.

Otherwise, in modern Windows (Vista, Seven, 8), you folder is located under `\Users`. Let's say the script `script.py` is the `Desktop` folder of user `Foo`, so it would be:

```
python c:\Users\Foo\Desktop\script.py
```

Comment: i did that; i got a syntax error: invalid syntax. command prompt thinks i'm typing code instead of trying to run a file? :(

Comment: You'd have to type it in outside of python

Answer (score 0):

Go like this:

- open a console
- > cd Desktop
- > c:\Python27\python first.py

Best to add `C:\Python27` to the system PATH variable though.

Comment: i get can't open file 'first.py' ; no such file or directory :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in command prompt:

```
start C:\Users\your_username_here\Desktop\first.py
```

You can even do this in python! Here is how:

```
import os
os.system("start "+yourPathHere)
```

A very simple program would be:

```
import os
while True:
    userInput=str(input("Enter file/app path: "))
    os.system("start "+userInput)
    print ("") # - just for the looks -
```

The more you know :p

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set up the path like this by adding this in the Environmental Variables: %path% on your settings.
`C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Python27`